# Azure Web App - Restore production slot backup with custom domain to a deployment slot

Tags: azure, backup, azure-web-app-service

**Scenario:**

Website myprod123.azurewebsites.net is hosted in Azure Web App with custom domain **myprod123.com**. I have a backup of  this website in Azure Storage. I would like to restore the backup to a deployment slot myprod123-**staging**.azurewebsites.net.

Using the Azure portal site https://portal.azure.com, I selected myprod123 and selected the backup (zip file) that I would like to restore. I changed the target slot to **staging** and clicked OK. After this, I got an error saying the restore process could not be started.

The root cause: the custom domain **myprod123.com** was already assigned.

How do I restore the backup?

Answer (score 2):

Doing the same steps on a website without custom domain will work. Apparently, the restore process (as of Jul 2015) of Azure Web App includes the custom domain.

The workaround was to edit the XML file that was created with the ZIP backup.

1. Download the XML file (I used Azure Storage Explorer)
2. Open the XML and remove the custom domain (`<d2p1:string>myprod123.com</d2p1:string>`)
3. Upload the XML.
4. Do the restore process.

Comment: Bad news. This neat trick is not working anymore in the new portal.